# how change url of this page on .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

So i have to change a url in .htaccess for SEO purposes, i already have a .htaccess file on the home directory of the site...

do i need to make the changes on the .htaccess on the home directory or on the subdirectory that is the web page that i need to have a new URL???

This is the code i already have on the home directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Redirect /public_html/cursos/YoutuberKids/index.php /public_html/cursos- 
kids/Youtuber/index.php
```

and this is the actual URL of the page that must be changed:

https://www.viahavok.com.br/cursos/GameDesignPRO/

And i need to become this URL:

https://www.viahavok.com.br/cursos/game-design-pro

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the name of the folder to 'game-design-pro'? Changing the URL in `.htaccess` isn't better or more effective when it comes to SEO in this case. (Unless I misunderstood your question?)

Comment: Is just because i dont want to change every <a> on the site that do not have php include for the navbar and footer

Comment: So to do that i will have to edit every single page of the site on the nav

Comment: Changing the URL would quite arguably have an effect on SEO.  People are much more likely to search for a "game design pro" than a "gamedesignpro".  Looks like OP wants a simple redirect solution vs manually changing their existing links.

Comment: I agree that &quot;game design pro&quot; is better than &quot;gamedesignPro&quot; but i just meant it would be equally good to change the name of the folder

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of the .htaccess file in the home directory:

```
RewriteRule ^cursos/GameDesignPRO/(.*)$ /cursos/game-design-pro/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This will redirect all resources in the directory.

- The `R=301` indicates that this is a permanent move for the
  resources.
- The `[L] flag` causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the    rule set.
  In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no    further
  rules will be processed.
- The `[NC] flag` causes the    RewriteRule to be matched in a
  case-insensitive manner.